# LSTM, regression or classification output layer

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently implementing an LSTM RNN with an underlying binary classification problem (0,1) and I am thinking what to choose as an output layer. From my point of view, both, regression and classification layer should work, right? Classification output layer: response variable categorical 0 and 1, Regression output layer: response variable number and for response >0.5 =1 <=0.5=0. Does this make sense? What are the potential benefits/downfalls of the two approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks require gradients to be trained. If you would do classification as you described, i.e.,
$$\hat{y} = f(s) = \begin{cases} 0 & s \leq 1 \\ 1 & s > 1 \end{cases},$$
it would be hard to define a gradient w.r.t. $s$, which is the output of the network. Therefore, you do not want to use classification in this sense.

Instead of pure classification, a trick called [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is generally used. Instead of directly predicting the class, the goal is to predict the probability that a sample is in the positive class.

Assuming that the binary labels are [binomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), logistic regression maximises the likelihood of the parameters for the given data. Therefore, you will want to use a logistic sigmoid at the end of your network in combination with the binary cross-entropy loss.

With (linear) regression, the output labels are assumed to have a Gaussian distribution, which is incorrect for binary classification. Since the binomial distribution assumption is clearly much closer to reality, you should get better results with logistic regression.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the overall layer structure you would recommend? Inputlayer, LSTM-layer, fully connected layer, regression layer?

Comment: Usually, a fully connected layer after an LSTM is not a bad idea. The final fully connected network will act as a "regression layer"; there is no need to make it something special. However, note that these are just common practices and do not necessarily make for better models.

Comment: The problem is that Matlab tells me that there is an output layer missing if I just use LSTM and a fully connected layer afterwards.